# Linq - Inner join with group with sum

Tags: linq

I have 2 tables, first table if transactions

transaction table:

```
 Id        LoanId
 1          100
```

The second table I have is a TransactionLeg table

transactionleg table:

```
ID  TransactionId GLAmount
1       1            200
2       1            200
```

I would like to join the two on the TransactionId column, group by the loanID and sum the GLAmount

So it should produce the following:

LoanId TotalGlAmount
  100     400

```
var investmentsWritten = from transaction in ctx.Transactions
                         join transactionleg in ctx.TransLegs on transaction.Id equals transactionleg.TransactionId
                         where
                         transaction.Class == Transaction.TransactionClasses.WriteOff &&
                         transaction.Created >= StartDate.Date && transaction.Created <= EndDate.Date
                         group transaction by transaction.LoanId
                         into g
                         select new { Id = g.Key, Value = _____ };
```

I was wondering what goes where the underline is, the value is transactionleg.GLAmount. I tried g.Sum(x => x.GLAmount) but GLAmount is not recognized, it is highlighted in red stating `Cannot resolve symbol GLAmount`

Comment: "that didnt work" doesn't tell us what happened when you tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `GLAmount` is in `transactionleg` not in `transaction`,
Modify your group by like this:

```
group new 
     { 
       transaction,
       transactionleg 
     } 
  by new
     {
       transaction.LoanId
     }
```

and now in Select:

```
select new 
      { 
        Id = g.Key, 
        Value = g.Sum(x=>x.transactionleg.GLAmount) 
      }
```